# Open a Web Page in a Windows Batch FIle

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, shellexecute

I have a **batch file** that does a bunch of things and at the end needs to **open up a web browser** to a page. Is there a way to, in essence, call `ShellExecute` on a **http** to open the web page?

Windows Command Prompt

Comment: When you say MS-DOS, I presume you mean Windows command prompt, not actual standalone MS-DOS?

Answer (score 257, accepted):

You can use the `start` command to do much the same thing as `ShellExecute`. For example

```
 start "" http://www.stackoverflow.com
```

This will launch whatever browser is the default browser, so won't necessarily launch Internet Explorer.

Comment: What if we want to open this webpage in a separate browser rather than the default one ?

Comment: @DulithDeCozta If you want to open a webpage in a specific browser that installed on the machine you'll need to use something like: `C:\path\to\browser.exe http://www.stackoverflow.com`. You should ask your own question if you need more details.

Comment: What reason to use empty quotation marks? As I see `start http://www.stackoverflow.com` is enough to open page in default browser.

Comment: @Daniechka It's in case the URL needs double quotes. The command `start "http://www.stackoverflow.com"` won't work, but the command `start "" "http://www.stackoverflow.com"` will.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27261692/how-do-i-use-quotes-in-cmd-start and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44219435/why-does-wrapping-an-argument-to-cmds-start-in-quotes-cause-it-to-behave-differ

Comment: start "chrome" http://localhost:8080 worked for me

Answer (score 6):

**1.To run from the default browser, use**

```
start http://www.stackoverflow.com
```

Please make sure that the appropriate browser is set as default at Control Panel-> default program :
[image]

**2.To launch page from specific browser, one can use**

```
start "iexplore.exe" http://www.stackoverflow.com

start "chrome.exe" http://www.stackoverflow.com

start "firefox.exe" http://www.stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: The second part of your answer is wrong. The first argument to start in parentheses is not the name of the executable, but the title of the windows. See `START /?`, and verify with a non-existing executable such as `start "moonlanding.exe" http://nasa.gov`.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the best method to approach this is to use Internet Explorer as it's a browser that is guaranteed to be on Windows based machines. This will also bring compatibility of other users which might have alternative browsers such as Firefox, Chrome, Opera..etc,

```
start "iexplore.exe" http://www.website.com
```

Comment: still opens the default browser. The first quoted argument isn't the program to use, but the window title (ignored in case of a browser)

Answer (score 2):

When you use the start command to a website it will use the default browser by default but if you want to use a specific browser then use `start iexplorer.exe www.website.com`

Also you cannot have `http://` in the url.

Comment: Are you sure it's not `iexplore.exe`

Comment: start "chrome" http://localhost:8080  worked for me. you answer is not 100% correct. thanks

Comment: Perhaps things have changed since your comment, but I now (Feb 2022) find http:// is accptable. A URL must start with either that or www. or both. Otherwise it gives a 'not found' error.

Answer (score 2):

`hh.exe` (help pages renderer) is capable of opening some simple webpages:

```
hh http://www.nissan.com
```

This will work even if browsing is blocked through:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer
```

Answer (score 0):

`start` did not work for me.

I used:

```
firefox http://www.stackoverflow.com
```

or

```
chrome http://www.stackoverflow.com
```

Obviously not great for distributing it, but if you're using it for a specific machine, it should work fine.

Comment: chrome is not recognized as internal or external command. i got this error

Comment: it worked with start chrome "website"