# How do I use quotes in cmd start?

Tags: shell, scripting, cmd

Here somthing I want to do.

```
start /wait ((c:\Program Files\NetDrive2\nd2cmd.exe) -c m -t ftp -blabla)
```

If I do

```
start /wait "c:\Program Files\NetDrive2\nd2cmd.exe -c m -t ftp -blabla"
```

Then there is an error because "Program Files" has a space.

If I do

```
start /wait "c:\Program Files\NetDrive2\nd2cmd.exe" -c m -t ftp -blabla
```

Then it interprets the argument for `start` so it also generates an error.

Is there anyway to overlap the equation like bracket in normal program language?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using the "start" command with parameters passed to the started program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154075/using-the-start-command-with-parameters-passed-to-the-started-program)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Reference [Start - Start a program, command or batch script (opens in a new window.)](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html)

> **Syntax**
>
> `START "title" [/D path] [options] "command" [parameters]`
>
> **Key**:
>
> `title`       Text for the CMD window title bar (required.)
>
> `path`        Starting directory.
>
> `command`     The command, batch file or executable program to run.
>
> `parameters`  The parameters passed to the command.

...

> Always include a **TITLE** this can be a simple string like "My Script" or just a pair of empty quotes "". According to the Microsoft documentation, the title is optional, but you may will have problems if it is omitted.

The reason you have an error if `title` is omitted is because the first `"` character (if present) will be used to delimit the title, so `start` will interpret `"Program Files"` as a title.

If there are no `"` characters then `title` can be omitted.

Your command should look like:

```
start /wait "My title" "c:\Program Files\NetDrive2\nd2cmd.exe" -c m -t ftp -blabla
```