# How to refresh available files in bat file

Tags: batch-file, installation, cmd

I have written a bat file that installs a software. After installing a software, it creates new files under "Program files" and I need to execute one of the newly created files. However when my bat script runs, it says that the path cannot be found. I believe this is because bat does not automatically refresh to get the new files. How would I do that?

Here is how my files goes:

```
"PATH\setup.exe" /quiet /qb USER_NAME=USERNAME PASSWORD=PASSWORD

call "C:\Program Files\PATH\file.bat" -u admin -p admin
```

This script is installing using setup.exe. After installation I have to run a bat file that is generated under Program files. Howeevr everytime that step fails by saying "path not found"

Comment: Try `start /wait "PATH\setup.exe" ...` instead.

Comment: then its not letting me use /quiet or /qb. They are required for the installation.

Comment: `start /wait "" "PATH\setup.exe" ...` because of [the quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27265635).

Comment: This still gave the same problem (at the end it said "The system cannot find the path specified") However, this time i cd into the directory and printed the contents of the directory that contains file.bat and it printed them right.

Comment: Check that the error does not come from the other `file.bat`. Otherwise if `setup.exe` launches a secondary installer asynchronously then that's harder to catch, though it would be rather unusual.

Comment: `start` is definitely not needed for this task. What is `PATH`?  The issue is most likely in `file.bat` which expects that the current directory is the directory of the batch file like on double clicking on `file.bat` from within Windows File Explorer. This is not the case. The current directory is surely not the directory `C:\Program Files\PATH`. The batch file must use `%~dp0` expanding to full path of batch file always ending with a backslash on referencing any file in same directory as the batch file like `"%~dp0ExeFile.exe"`.

Comment: Are you sure `setup.exe` created a directory in `%ProgramFiles%` (usually `C:\Program Files`) and not in directory `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` (usually `C:\Program Files (x86)`) on a machine with 64-bit Windows? I recommend to read the Microsoft documentation [WOW64 Implementation Details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/wow64-implementation-details).

Comment: Before running the file.bat, i am already going into the subdirectories that contain the .bat file. Before running the bat file, I even printed all the dir contents using “dir” and it printed them correctly with .bat file included in there.

Comment: I just checked and its using %~dp0 in the file.bat. However, I am cd into the dir with file.bat before running it . Is that not enough?

Comment: @VaibhavChadha That should be enough. Well, I think we need to see the contents of `file.bat` or you [debug the batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42448601/3074564) by yourself to find out which command line produces the error message and what is the reason for not finding the path of a file or directory.