# batch file: prompt user for a value from .txt and run the second line

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I am very new to batch scripting.  I am trying to ask the user to input a known variable from the first row of a text file called camera.txt.

camera.txt contains:

**cam52**     http://192.168.101.52/reboot.cgi?delay=555

**cam53**     http://192.168.101.53/reboot.cgi?delay=555

If user inputs **cam52** it would proceed to start IE with the second row's value
"**column two in text file**"

I have the following thus far but unsure if I am even in the right path...

```
 @echo off

 Title Input Camera and Reboot

  ECHO input camera to restart

 ......?

 FOR /f "tokens=2 delims= " %%b IN (camera.txt) DO ECHO Launching Internet  Explorer with camera URL %%b

 Start "" "%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "%%b"
```

What do I make it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Let's start with getting user input.**
From [In Windows cmd, how do I prompt for user input and use the result in another command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223721/in-windows-cmd-how-do-i-prompt-for-user-input-and-use-the-result-in-another-com)

```
set /p id="Enter ID: "
```

---

**Second, looping throught the file.**

You've already got this close to figured out.  Kudos.  However, we need to get both pieces of the line.  `tokens=2` will just get the second piece (the URL).  So we will change it a bit...

```
FOR /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%a IN (camera.txt) DO
```

See http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html for more info on this.

---

**Third, a comparison.**

[From ss64's `if` documentation:](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html)

```
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 2 goto sub_problem2
```

---

**Fourth, opening the page/browser**

From another SO question: [Open a Web Page in a Windows Batch FIle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26223936/open-a-web-page-in-a-windows-batch-file)

```
start "" http://www.stackoverflow.com
```

---

**Summary**

So, if we add all those together, we get something like this:

```
@echo off
REM Title Input Camera and Reboot

set /p cam="input camera to restart: " 

FOR /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%a IN (camera.txt) DO (
    if %%a EQU %cam% (
        ECHO Launching Internet Explorer with camera URL %%b
        start "" %%b
    )
)
```

Comment: WOW!   It makes complete sense now.  You are amazing.  Thanks!