# Why does wrapping an argument to CMD's start in quotes cause it to behave differently?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

This just took up a good chunk of my time to debug in a batch script:

```
:: Opens up Chrome
start C:\cygwin64\home\james\code\cs\PolynomialReducer\reports\PolynomialReducer.Tests\index.htm

:: Opens a new command prompt
start "C:\cygwin64\home\james\code\cs\PolynomialReducer\reports\PolynomialReducer.Tests\index.htm"
```

Why/is there any reason the `start` command behaves differently if you wrap your argument in quotes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first quoted argument is assumed to be a window title. If you insert an empty set of quotes between `start` and the quoted command, you should observe expected behaviour.

Comment: On a related note, this startup window title is used to load and save settings for the new console window (e.g. screen/window size, font face/size, colors, transparency), which gets stored in the registry key `HKCU\Console\[title]`.

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention that using `start ""` sets an empty title on the new console window. Take care to not modify the the console settings on this window. If you do, when it exits the console will happily write the settings that you modified back to the defaults in `HKCU\Console` and completely remove all other default settings except for a few global settings.